# Algorithm Time Complexity: i/=2 in loops

Tags: algorithm

```
int fun(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            count += 1;
    return count;
}
```

I'm a very new to the time complexities calculations. For this algorithm, I get the answer to be O(nlogn), but the answer is apparently O(n).

My logic was the outer loop has an exponential decline and will occur log_base2_(N) times. The inner loop will run a total of N times as it becomes a geometric sum (first iteration it is N/2 times, then N/4, then N/8 ...). If I put these together and multiply them as a result of the nested loop, that's where I'm coming up with O(NlogN). 
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outer loop would run a total of log(n) times. Now if you observe the inner loop it first time it runs n times, next n/2 times and so on, so it makes the series

```
n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...)
```

the sum of this would be **(2*n)**, That means it is O(n)

Hence the time complexity is O(n) since outer loop runs O(logn) times and inner loop runs O(n) times.

It is not O(nlogn) since the inner loop does not take n steps each time, in fact the sum of all steps taken would be O(n)

Comment: This is helpful. I think I was confusing the total number of operations with the running time. If I understand your point correctly, the time complexity will be the worse of the two loops, which in this case is O(n).

Comment: @user6142489 in general it is not the worst of the two loops, but the total number of iterations of the innermost loop. Thus, as pointed out in this answer, we need to perform the respective sum which gives the total of O(n). Note however that the usual procedure is to take the _product_ of the complexities of each loop (thus not the _max_), but this results here in a too loose bound, because the number of iterations of the innermost loop varies depending on the current value of _i_.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.