# I am unable to find the complexity of the code that I have seen interview bit. plz see my below code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Below code I have seen in interview bit and I am unable to find the time complexity of the code

```
int  a = 0   ,   i = N;
while (i > 0) {
    a += i;
    i /= 2;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm Time Complexity: i/=2 in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195687/algorithm-time-complexity-i-2-in-loops)

Answer (score 2):

It is log(N). Since the step of loop is dividing by 2, you have log2(N) loops.